# can't see apk on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxe

I'm developing a game with Haxe NME, and Android 2.2 (SDK 8, the version supported by haxe nme). I have been able to upload the files using adb, I see it in DDMS explorer, and the counter of data of the SD emulator see the occupied space. now the problem is that when I go to aplications -> manage aplication -> on sdcard I can't see any item to be able to install it and test it.

I tried with my APK, and the astro manager apk too, all is the same nothing appears. i have the option "third party aplication" checked, and I'm on Windows 7.

Anyone can give me a hint of what i need to do to see the apk in the emulator and install it?

Comment: Are you using `adb install` to install it?

Comment: @Nick same time! Comment notifications (like answer notifications) would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not asking of how to install it from adb, i'm asking how i can see it directly from the emulator, in the section of manage aplications -> on sdcard

Comment: ok, all of you was right, that is what i needed to do, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually install an application, you need to do `adb install`.

Say that you're in `C:\` and your apk file is also in `C:\`

```
adb install myApk.apk
```

When you simply push an apk, it doesn't install it, hence the need for `adb install`.

Comment: I'm not asking of how to install it from adb, i'm asking how i can see it directly from the emulator, in the section of manage aplications -> on sdcard

Comment: ok, all of you was right, that is what i needed to do, thanks :)